# JS code not executed after hitting the back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have this code:

```
// After page is loaded
$(window).bind("load", function () {
    // Avoid flickering
    $('#authentication').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

Why ".removeClass('hidden')" is only working when the page is first loaded. If I navigate to another page and hit the back button the 'hidden' class of my div (`<div id="authentication" class="hidden">`) is applied from the CSS side but not removed using the JS code above.

I was told that might be caused by browser caching the thing.

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: have you tried doing it without jquery? E.g: `window.onload=function(){...}`

Comment: Because you're using a buggy browser that saves the initial state of a page and doesn't fire the load event when pressing the back button. You should indicate which browser(s) you're having issues with.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté That buggy browser is Chrome, latest version (30.0.1599.69).

Comment: Uhm, I was pretty sure that this was fixed at Chromium quite a few versions back. I'll check again.

Comment: @Markasoftware I just did. No difference: window.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById("authentication").className = ""; }

Comment: Works for me on Chrome stable 30 / Canary 32 [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r9FEK/2/show/). Can you provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) where it doesn't work?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I am using Ember.js so my URLs looks like this: `/`, `/#/register` and `/#/login`. I guess Chrome is not considering that a new page.

Comment: Have you tried with on ready instead of on load?

Comment: @ST3 Yes, same issue.

Comment: Seems like you're using ember's hash location implementation (akin to the History API) so you won't get `load` events when pressing the back button.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Yes. I'm not familiar with Ember so I don't know the proper way to do this, but the hackish solution would be listening to the `hashchange` event.

Comment: Better tag the question with Ember.js so that people with experience in Ember can answer this properly. `=]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Ember.js routing you need to move this code inside your controller as you no longer have page load events